# How to catch Command+W key action in OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, key, nswindow

I subclassed NSWindows and implemented the **keyDown:** and **keyUp:** method like this:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"Down: '%@'", [event characters]);
    [super keyDown:event];
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"Up: '%@'", [event characters]);
    [super keyUp:event];
}
```

If I pressed "W" key, it prints both my "Down" and "Up" correctly. But If I pressed Command+W combination, It prints ONLY the "Down" message, and windows' close action was not triggered. How should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command-W is typically the key equivalent of a menu item. It is handled by the menu when it is told to `-performKeyEquivalent:`. The menu item sends its action method to its target. The action method is typically `-performClose:` and the target is usually the first responder.

So, the normal processing of Command-W does not use the window's `-keyDown:` or `-keyUp:` at all.

If you want to control whether the window closes, have the window delegate implement `-windowShouldClose:`. If you want to be notified when the window is about to close, implement `-windowWillClose:` in the window delegate or observe the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification.

Regarding keyboard handling, a quirk of `-[NSApplication sendEvent:]` is that it just doesn't dispatch any key up event if the Command key was down. If for some reason you really need to see the key up event, you'll have to implement a custom subclass of `NSApplication`, configure your Info.plist to make sure it's used, and implement an override of `-sendEvent:`.

Comment: As ken says, you don't normally do it like thus for extremely common commands in cocoa. Read up on the responder chain and NSApplication and NSApplication Delegate protocol

Comment: Thanks! And I realized whether my Control+W does not work: I hid the "File" menu on top! But why I could not catch the Connand key? Was it caught by NSMenu Object?

Comment: You mean why didn't you see the press of the Command key in your `-keyDown:` method? Because changes in the state of the modifier keys are not delivered as key-up or key-down events. They are delivered as flags-changed events. If you had a `-flagsChanged:` method, it would have been called.